# How to check for a condition and update values in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is a part of the code I am using to write a datatable to a csv file:

```
foreach (DataRow row in reportDataTable.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
```

Is it possible to check for empty strings in the collection and replace them with a default text, like "Not Available" before appending to StringBuilder object?

I am using:

```
foreach (var fieldValue in fields)
{
    if (fieldValue.ToString() == "\"\"")
        fieldValue.Replace("\"\"", "\"N.A.\"");
}
```

But the cells remain blank in the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.Select()` if you want to change what you select:

```
var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.ToString()) ? "\"N/A\"" : string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));

stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
```

Comment: The server on which the application was hosted stopped working unexpectedly. It became accessible again just a few minutes ago. Implementing what you suggested in the answer was the first thing I did.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `IEnumerable<string> fields` is pointing to a `.Select()` object of type IEnumerable. Every time you do `foreach` over the fields object, it will *start all over* asking the IEnumerable object for items, which does so by calling the body of the lambda expression.

Never mind if you change the values that you got during such a loop; they vanish as soon as the `foreach` ends.
When `string.Join` starts it does its own `foreach`, and it will get freshly generated values instead of the ones you thought you set.

One fix would simply be to materialize it all into a collection, using `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`. Only then you have a collection of objects, instead of a "definition of how to construct objects".

So e.g. like this:

```
var fields = row
    .ItemArray
    .Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""))
    .ToArray();
```